# Creating bootstrap form with mixed rows of single input and multiple input in each rows

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I wanted to make my form looks like this:

```
Label1
[Input                       ]
Label2
[Dropbox][Input         ][btn]
ArbitraryLabel3
[Input                       ]
ArbitraryLabel4
[Input                       ]
```

It is a mixed of horizontal and vertical but I wanted the inputs on label2 to look like it is using the form-inline, but the rest of the forms are horizontally aligned.  Is there a proper way of doing this instead of using col?  col class makes the inputs form gaps between them when the page is resized.

EDIT:
Here is a sample minimal code:

```
<form>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label> Label 1 </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label> Label 2 </label>
      <select class="form-control">
        <option selected value="opt1"> opt1 </option>
        <option value="opt2"> opt2 </option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
        </button>
      </span>
  </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please post a minimal, working example of your code (HTML/CSS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the field examples you gave it is possible to use [Bootstrap's input groups](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons-dropdowns) inside any type of form layout. It supports labels/hints/text, checkboxes, radio buttons, buttons, segmented/grouped/multiple buttons, dropdown buttons, plus one "real" form input type.

It doesn't support `<textarea>` or `<select>`, or multiple form fields in a single row though.

Example http://jsfiddle.net/zfachxus/1/

```
<div class="input-group">

    <!-- DROPDOWN BUTTON -->
    <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <!-- add links here -->
        </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- TEXT FIELD -->
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Input box" aria-label="...">

    <!-- PLAIN BUTTON -->
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
            Button
        </button>
    </span>

</div>
```

Comment: wow! It did the trick!  Sorry I did not see your reply before I edited my post but yes, your answer is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: Your answer is great but I'm just airing out my opinion on bootstrap because I think it is counter-intuitive to not support select on that setup.  I'm pretty sure I'm not the only one who would use that combination, i.e. select+input+btn in one line combined with other form inputs but not supporting select seems bad.  I hope bootstrap will support that on v4.